# ExtJS how to reference region panel in viewport

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewport, extjs-mvc, extjs5

Hi I have a problem about extjs viewport. I created a button and tried to reference to east panel but It seems a wrong way to access panel. Chrome developer tools showed a message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"
I google this [thread](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?56202-How-get-region-from-Viewport)
but my code is still not work.

my viewport:

```
var viewport = Ext.define('Fiddle.view.Viewport', {
extend: 'Ext.container.Viewport',
layout: 'border',

items: [{
    // xtype: 'container',
    // itemId: 'header',
    region: 'north',
    //html: '<h1 class="x-panel-header">Page Title</h1>',
    border: false,
    margin: '0 0 5 0',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'collapse',
        handler: function() {
            var east = viewport.items.get('e');
            if (!!east.collapsed) {
                east.expand();
            } else {
                east.collapse();
            }
       }
    }]
}, {
    region: 'east',
    title: 'east Panel',
    itemId: 'e',
    //collapsible: true,
    //collapseMode: 'mini',
    floatable: false,
    html: 'Information goes here',
    split: true,
    placeholder:{ 
        width:20,
        items:[{
            xtype:'button',
        }]
    }
}, {
    region: 'center',
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        html: 'Center'
    }
}]
})
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `viewport.items.get('e')`, use [`down`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-down):

```
viewport.down('#e')
```

**Update:**

In your code sample, `viewport` is referencing the viewport *class*, not instance. To access the instance from the button clicked, use:

```
b.up('viewport').down('#e')
```

Full example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rl2

Comment: it is still not work. I have set autoCreateViewport: true. Is the problem here?

Comment: What does it return then? Did you check in the console? `autoCreateViewport` should not matter as long as `viewport` is still referencing your viewport and the east panel has `itemId: 'e'`.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: viewport.down is not a function

Comment: Your `viewport` variable references the class, not instance. Answer updated.

Comment: Thank  you @DrakeES ! The two ways are really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using itemId's. Doesn't
`b.up('viewport').down('container[region=east]');`
do the trick?

Comment: Hi Tarabass. I tried your suggestion and test `b.up('viewport').down('container[region=east]');` It can do the trick but in this case, placeholder items will show on incorrect place.

Comment: That's strange. A reference to an instance should be a reference to an instance, no matter what selector you are using. Well, I never used a placeholder like that, maybe your problem is in there.